# mysql increment order by AZ

Tags: mysql

I want to add a column INT(10) to a TABLE, this column show be 1 to x depending on a column a to 7

```
title --> number
Aazdfze  --> 1
Bsfzdvgf  --> 2
Csgzb  --> 3
...
```

number should be = to ORDER BY  title ASC

thank you

Comment: So why store this value at all?

Answer (score 1):

got it

```
SET @sort := 0;
UPDATE mytable 
SET `ordering` = @sort := @sort + 1 ORDER BY title;
```